# Discord.py music bot program

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to write a discord music bot, but after hours of search and different tutorials, I cannot get it to work. Here is my code so far:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.command()
async def music(ctx):
  
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    voiceChannel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name='Music')

    await voiceChannel.connect()
    await voice.connect()
  
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))


client.run('TOKEN')
```

When I run the bot, it joins the Voice Channel, but does not play any music

I have tried lots of things and it won't work. I heard it has something to do with `discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)`, but I can't seem to find an alternative.

(I know there are answers online, but they don't work for me)

Please Help,

Thanks, Haniel

Comment: _I know there are answers online, but they don't work for me_ - what's the difference in your code which makes them not work?

Comment: They have one that gets a youtube link, but mine dose not, so I modified their code, but it wont work.

Comment: Can you try passing the `executable` and static `source` in `discord.FFmpegPCMAudio()`?

Comment: I am sorry, I am new at this. Could you give me an example?

Comment: You have to check if FFmpeg is installed in your system or not. If not, then install it and run your program again. If it is installed, then specify the path like this: `discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:/path/ffmpeg.exe", source="C:/songpath")`

Comment: I tried what you said, but I am getting a OpusNotInstalled error

Comment: You can add this line after importing discord : `discord.opus.load_opus()`

Comment: I tried everything you said, but I got a error in the terminal saying: module opus not found, even after installing. What module should I import? Opuslib? Opustools?

Comment: You can try different ways from here: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/783

Comment: load_opus() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
This is the error I get when I import opus and type: discord.opus.load_opus()

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63325481/6480803